# Stored procedure from T-SQL in C#

Tags: c#, t-sql

I create stored procedure in T-SQL

```
CREATE PROCEDURE price_proc  @type_of_service int, @date_of_receipt date, @date_of_delivery date, @mechanic_id int, @car_id_p int, @price_for_work float
AS
DECLARE @count int, @car_id int
SELECT @car_id = car_id, @count = COUNT(car_id) FROM work WHERE car_id = @car_id_p GROUP BY car_id 
IF(@count > 1 AND @count < 4 )
BEGIN
    SET @price_for_work =  @price_for_work - (@price_for_work * 0.1)
    INSERT INTO work(type_of_service_id, date_of_receipt, date_of_delivery, mechanic_id, car_id, price_for_work) VALUES (@type_of_service, @date_of_receipt, @date_of_delivery, @mechanic_id, @car_id_p, @price_for_work)
END
ELSE IF(@count > 4)
BEGIN
    SET @price_for_work = @price_for_work - (@price_for_work * 0.15)
    INSERT INTO work(type_of_service_id, date_of_receipt, date_of_delivery, mechanic_id, car_id, price_for_work) VALUES (@type_of_service, @date_of_receipt, @date_of_delivery, @mechanic_id, @car_id_p, @price_for_work)
END
GO
```

I call it in my code

```
string d1 = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", dateTimePicker1.Value);
string d2 = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", dateTimePicker2.Value);

cmd = new SqlCommand("price_proc", SqlConn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@type_of_service", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = type_of_service_id;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@date_of_receipt", SqlDbType.Date)).Value = d1;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@date_of_delivery", SqlDbType.Date)).Value = d2;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@mechanic_id", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = mechanic_id;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@car_id_p",SqlDbType.Int)).Value = car_id;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@price_for_work", SqlDbType.Float)).Value = price;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But it does not work? I print cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() and give -1. Help me please.

Comment: put the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` around a try{}catch{} and tell us what the error is.. also when you run this line manually `SELECT @car_id = car_id, @count = COUNT(car_id) FROM work WHERE car_id = @car_id_p GROUP BY car_id ` what results are returned.. also what if count is = to 1 or count is = to 4..? `IF(@count >= 1 AND @count < 4 )` and the second one should check if >= 4

Answer (score 1):

You either need to Select a result set, or return an integer from your stored procedure.  By the looks of your code, I imagine you may wish to return the SCOPE_IDENTITY, which will equal the newly inserted ID.